# How to get userInfo from NSError in catch clause

Tags: swift, error-handling, swift2

If I have a throwing method, like so:

```
func doSomethingWithString(string:String) throws {
  guard string.characters.count > 0 else {
    throw NSError(domain: "CustomErrorDomain", code: 42, userInfo: ["foo" : "bar"])
  }
  // Do something with string...
}
```

Then I try to call it and read the `userInfo`:

```
do {
  try doSomethingWithString("")
} catch let error as NSError {
  print(error.domain)
  print(error.code)
  print(error.userInfo)
}
```

... it comes back as an empty dictionary, (but the domain and code are correctly populated):

```
CustomErrorDomain
42
[:]
```

But if I add in this extra step:

```
do {
  try doSomethingWithString("")
} catch let e {
  let error = e as NSError
  print(error.domain)
  print(error.code)
  print(error.userInfo)
}
```

...it works:

```
CustomErrorDomain
42
[foo: bar]
```

Does anybody know why this might be?

FYI - I am on Xcode 7 beta 2 (7A121l)

Comment: Very interesting... Don't know why this could happen

Comment: I consider this as a bug, please file a radar at bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Okay, @RobertVojta. I have now filed a radar.

Comment: This one is fixed in Xcode 7 Beta 4. Does work now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug, fixed in Xcode 7 Beta 4. Here's extracts from the Release Notes ([PDF](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7_beta_4/Xcode_7_beta_4_Release_Notes.pdf), page 15):

> **Resolved Issues in Xcode 7 beta 4 — Swift 2.0 and Objective-C**
>
> When
>   throwing a reference to an NSError instance in Swift, the Swift
>   runtime no longer loses the userInfo of the original NSError if it is
>   caught as an NSError. The Swift runtime now preserves the identity of
>   the original NSError. For example, this assertion now holds:

```
 let e = NSError(...)
 do {
   throw e
 } catch let e2 as NSError {
   assert(e === e2)
 }
```